# IIS does not reflect my ASP.NET MVC View changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, razor, webserver

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application on an IIS server and I have implemented some changes to a view (adding javascript code to it) but when I update the web in the IIS, I still get the web NOT modified in the browser.

I have tried to restart the IIS server (by command and manually), to recycle the application pool, to update the web and restart it, to modify the web.config, etc and it keeps sending me the not updated one in the browser.

Comment: Did you try Ctrl + F5 in your browser

Comment: Try Ctrl+R and Ctrl+F5 which will clear browser cache

Comment: Try Ctrl + F5 in your browser

Comment: Yes, I tried CTRL + F5, CTRL + R and Shift + F5 but none of them worked

Comment: Check if you publish options are allowing updates. Probably your views are precompiled.